# Isotope in down slided div

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

**Case**: I have slideDown/slideUp divs. For initiation my first div (#nav) slides down to choose a language. When chosen, the div is slided up and the grid's div (#content) slides down. I am using Isotope to layout the grid (.section).

**Problem 1**: when the grid is displayed, the isotope elements are not positioned near each other but all are in the same left/top position. The elements go to their places when i resize the window.

**Problem 2**: the filter buttons do not filter.

**Question**: how to let the elements to be well positioned without resizing the screen and what is wrong with my filter codes that buttons do not work ?

**Codes**

After preloading the body fades in and the nav slides down (*i deleted the jpreloader script to make the fiddle simplier*) :

```
$('body').hide();

$('body').fadeIn(300);
// language nav is shown initially
$('#nav').animate({'top':300}, 2000, 'easeOutElastic');
```

When the nav button is clicked, it slides up, the content div slides down together with the nav-call button :

```
$('#fr').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#francais').delay(1700).slideDown(800);
    $('#nav').slideUp(800);
    $('#call-nav').animate({'top':20}, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
});
$('#call-nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav').delay(1700).slideDown(800);
    $('#francais').slideUp(800);
    $(this).animate({'top':-80}, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
});
```

Isotope functions (init, filter, selected button):

```
// init Isotope
$('.section').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.box-sizer'
    }
});
// bind filter button click
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });
});
```

HTML and CSS codes are in the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/k9Lxota7/12/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isotope needs to be triggered on a container & items that are visible. Otherwise, it is unable to measure the sizes of everything.
Sticking with your code, one can get around this by using  visibility: hidden; instead of display:none, 
Set your body and .section to  visibility: hidden; instead of display:none.
Use jquery to show the divs to and change the css to  visibility: visible; and then tell isotope to "layout".
If you want to have certain divs always visible in isotope, then us the stamp method.(see jsfiddle).
Your filter code is calling functions and using variables ($container, filterFnctns) that you haven't defined.

Here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/7jyp30n9/)** with all of the above changes

The code:

```
$('body').hide().css('visibility', 'visible');

$('.section').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    percentPosition: true,
    stamp: '.stamp',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.box-sizer'
    }
});

$('body').fadeIn(300);
// init Isotope
$('.section').isotope('layout');
// bind filter button click
$('#filters').on('click', 'button', function () {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value

    $('.section').isotope({
        filter: filterValue
    });
});
// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each(function (i, buttonGroup) {
    var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
    $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function () {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });
});
// language nav is shown initially
$('#nav').animate({
    'top': 300
}, 2000, 'easeOutElastic');

$('#fr').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#francais').delay(1700).slideDown(800);
    $('#nav').slideUp(800);
    $('#call-nav').animate({
        'top': 20
    }, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
    $('.section').hide().css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('body').fadeIn(300);
});
$('#call-nav').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav').delay(1700).slideDown(800);
    $('#francais').slideUp(800);
    $(this).animate({
        'top': -80
    }, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect, i accepted your answer and also voted for it as that was really complicated for me... in the meantime i changed the html structure, so the .is-checked class change did not work, i changed the code for this one :
`$('.button-group .is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
 $(this).addClass('is-checked');`